# Capturing PCM data from AVPlayer playback of HLS

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, http-live-streaming

We are trying to use capture the PCM data from an HLS stream for processing, ideally just before it is played, though just after is acceptable. We want to do all this while still using AVPlayer.

Has anyone done this? For non-HLS streams, as well as local files, this seems to be possible with the MPAudioProcessingTap, but not with HLS. This issue discusses doing it with non-HLS:
[AVFoundation audio processing using AVPlayer's MTAudioProcessingTap with remote URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833796/avfoundation-audio-processing-using-avplayers-mtaudioprocessingtap-with-remote)

Thanks!

Comment: Not working for Icecast MP3 streams either, at least for me.  Meanwhile, remote files of finite length (e.g. non-radio) as well as local files work fine.  Strangely, it even works when the remote files are played before they finish buffering (much like a remote livestream). I wonder what’s going on in Apple’s implementation that’s causing that discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this has been confirmed to be unsupported, at least for the time being.

From an Apple engineer:

> The MTAudioProcessingTap is not available with HTTP live streaming. I suggest filing an enhancement if this feature is important to you - and it's usually helpful to describe the type of app you're trying to design and how this feature would be used.

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45966

Our best bet is to file enhancement radars to try to get them to devote some development time towards it. I am in the same unfortunate boat as you.